# Antlr4 problems with negativ sign and operator

Tags: regex, antlr4

Hello we have this antlr4 Tree Parser:

```
grammar calc;

calculator: (d)*;

c
    : c '*' c
    | c '/' c
    | c '+' c
    | c '-' c
    | '(' c ')'
    | '-'? 
    | ID
    ;
d: ID '=' c;

NBR: [0-9]+; 
ID:  [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

The Problem is if I use a -, antlr4 doesn´t recognize, if is it ja sign or operator for sepcial inputs like: (-2-4)*4. For Inputs like this antlr4 doesn´t understand that the - befor the 2 belongs to the constant 2 and that the - is not a operator.

Comment: It's been some time for me with antlr but I think you need to define the possibility of a '-' in NBR. Because so far your 'NBR' only consists of 0 to 9 and no '-'. So NBR: -?[0-9]+; should do the trick I think.

Comment: @Eskapone no, that way a space between the minus and a number will mess things up, and will also cause `-1-2` to be tokenized as 2 `NBR` tokens, and therefor not be accepted by the parser

Comment: You're missing the '+' unary operator as well. See how it's done [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/ce3619a87a455b13c6d6a793f0649be077025b3f/arithmetic/arithmetic.g4#L46).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
c
 : '-' c
 | c ('*' | '/') c
 | c ('+' | '-') c
 | '(' c ')'
 | ID
 | NBR
 ;
```

That way all these will be OK:

- `-1`
- `- 2`
- `-3-4`
- `5+-6`
- `-(7*8)`
- `(-2-4)*4`

For example, `(-3-10)*10` is parsed like this:

[image]

#### EDIT

This is what happens when I parse `9+38*(19+489*243/1)*1+3`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    | '-'?
```

should be:

```
    | '-'? NBR
```

You need to specify that it's a NBR that may (or may not) be preceded by a `-`

Comment: I made this for example: input: (-2-3)*14  the problem is that the tree sees now the - as from the -2 as a operator and not as a sign. I dont get a error but the - from the 2 dont belongs to the 2

Comment: You have: (c (c ( (c (c - 2) - (c 5)) )) * (c 10)) correct would be (c (c ( (c (c -2) - (c 5)) )) * (c 10)) so you need -2 not - 2, because - 2 means, that the - is a operator, not a sign. Not space between the - and the 2, because - is not a operator, its belongs to the 2